# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException without using FXMLLoader

Tags: java, javafx

I've recently started out with JavaFX and I am trying to make a Coin Toss application that shows a picture of the coin respective to what was rolled. I've already done a dice roll simulator with similar code to this but for some reason, I am receiving an error that I didn't for that.

CoinToss class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

public class CoinToss extends Application {
    Image heads = new Image("D:\\Downloads - DATA\\heads1.png");
    Image tails = new Image("D:\\Downloads - DATA\\tails1.png");
    ImageView viewCoin;
    Label resultCoin;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label1 = new Label("Welcome to the Coin Flipper!");
        Label label2 = new Label("Please hit start to flip the coin!");
        
        resultCoin = new Label();
        Button startButton = new Button("Start!");
        
        startButton.setOnAction(new StartButtonHandler());
        
        
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10, label1,label2, startButton, viewCoin, resultCoin);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(12));
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        
        Scene simulatorScene = new Scene(vbox,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(simulatorScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    class StartButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            int num = 0;
            String word = "";
            CoinValue value = new CoinValue();
            value.roll1();
            num = value.getRoll1();
            if(num == 0) {
                viewCoin = new ImageView(heads);
                word = "heads";
            } else {
                viewCoin = new ImageView(tails);
                word = "tails";
            }
            resultCoin.setText("You rolled a " + word);
        }
    }
}
```

CoinValue class

```
package application;

import java.util.Random;

public class CoinValue {
    int rollnum;
    public void roll1()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        rollnum = rand.nextInt(1) + 1;
    }
    public int getRoll1()
    {
        return rollnum;
    }
}
```

I have tried to find an answer from StackOverflow many times but I can't seem to find one that fits my issue since I am not using FXMLLoader.

Error Message

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Children: child node is null: parent = VBox@4ac2de6c
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:542)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:233)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:103)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.layout.VBox.<init>(VBox.java:252)
    at HelloFX/application.CoinToss.start(CoinToss.java:34)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.CoinToss
```

Comment: The `StartButtonHandler` code does not run until the `Button` is pressed. Yet, the `VBox` needs the `ImageView`. Go ahead and declare and assign the `ImageView`. Then in the handler use `viewCoin.setImage(...);`

Answer (score 0):

`resultCoin` has not been initialized when you add them to the VBox.

Comment: `resultCoin` is initialized to a `new Label()`

Comment: I missed that line, `viewCoin` is unassigned until your button handler is called though.

Comment: I assigned viewCoin and it worked. Thanks a lot!